# How do I avoid code duplication and apply Boolean operator only to the source of image?

Tags: reactjs

How can I make this code better so that there is no code duplication and the boolean operator is only applied to `src` of the image. So, when the link named `car` is clicked the car image shows up otherwise when it is the other link clicked then bike image shows up.

```
{props.type == 'car'? <img src={carImage} className="w-75"/> : <img src={bikeImage} className="w-75"/>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src={props.type === 'car' ? carImage : bikeImage} className="w-75"/>
```